# Kattis phonelist issue

Tags: c#

Once I run the following local, it is woking fast, but when I submit it to Kattis, It only exceeds 2/5 and I get Time Limit Exceeded. 
Any suggestion?
I have tried with a input file with 10000 numbers and it is still fast localy :S

```
using System;


namespace phonelist
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int nrOfPhoneNrs = 0;
            bool consistent;

            int nrOfTestCases = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());
            for (byte i = 0; i < nrOfTestCases; i++)
            {
                consistent = false;
                nrOfPhoneNrs = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().Trim());
                string[] phList = new string[nrOfPhoneNrs];
                int n = 0;
                while (n < nrOfPhoneNrs)
                {
                    phList[n] = Console.ReadLine();
                    n++;
                }

                Array.Sort(phList);
                int runs = nrOfPhoneNrs - 1;
                for (int p = 0; p < runs; p++)
                {
                    if (phList[p + 1].StartsWith(phList[p]))
                    {
                        consistent= true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(consistent? "NO" : "YES");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on the machine against which code is getting executed. could be  your machine has more computing power.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how will I exceed then?

Comment: Just a side note... `result` is a very bad name for your boolean value. Not to mention it is opposite of what you output (this is correct, but only more confusing due to bad naming). Also should probably use `int` instead of `byte` for the outer-most loop variable. And `Array.Clear` does nothing here - the variable leaves scope right after you clear the array.

Comment: Thank you, I read somewhere that byte is faster than int, thats whay I used it.

Comment: Test your beliefs. `Stopwatch` is great

Comment: Im using Stopwatch, and it exceeds under 1.5 sec, but according to Kattis it is not fast :S

Comment: To increase performance, take a look at the mechanics that you are using. Isolate what slows you down, and find a faster alternative. You don't test `byte` vs `int` using this code - you isolate it so most of the test's body is just that `byte` vs `int`. I doubt you'll find performance difference there. Try reading all lines to memory once, instead of one line at a time in the loop - what does that do? And when you test that - only test that (phone numbers are irrelevant to which reading mechanism is faster)

Comment: First you time every separate mechanism on it's own, to find where the bottleneck is. Reading lines? Looping numbers? The sorting? If you find that the algorithm for testing a set of phone-numbers as a whole is what slows you down, and the inner-mechanisms of it have no better alternatives - think of a different algorithm with less complexity, or better optimize it for the unique requirements of your problem.

Comment: Those were generic tips. But you can't benchmark performance on a different machine than the one you're running the tests on. I don't know how Kattis work, but maybe you can output benchmark results for yourself to see when you submit your code, to find where it differs from your machine on a significant level?

Comment: Thank you, I will try follow your tips despite I already have  done some of them, the problem is I cant see the problem Kattis is encountring, as mentioned it is fast on my machine which make it hard for my find the bottleneck. I will give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your main problem is that you're using `StartsWith` and `Array.Sort` methods.

I don't want to give you too detailed advice (so that you can still solve it by yourself) but let me just suggest considering a different data structure than an array of strings, perhaps `HashSet<string>`.